# Windows Phone 7 not setting image

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to set an image source but it's failing.  The image is :

http://www.google.com/s2/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAAAhCI7V2pmUht_4DhC4nYWU8pajqRcYx5iUquORlMaOATABBYVUEen14cvZFQ35MWRjpDJeK-M?sz=32

if I do

```
<image source="http://www.google.com/s2/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAAAhCI7V2pmUht_4DhC4nYWU8pajqRcYx5iUquORlMaOATABBYVUEen14cvZFQ35MWRjpDJeK-M?sz=32" />
```

It works fine in design, but not run.

Any idea how to get this to work right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That image link doesn't work for me -- and that's very likely your problem.  In design mode, you probably have a cached copy of the image showing up, whereas in run mode, the emulator (or device) is trying to fetch a new copy and cannot.

Confirm a URL that is stateless, and try that?

--randy

Comment: @John - Doesn't work for me either. However, since the setting is private, could it be something to do with cookies?

Comment: Yea I'm assuming it's a cookie thing, I'm trying to figure out how to make it public or at least usable as an image, so far no luck.  Not like I can pop a cookie on the request to get the image either...  I definatly don't want to have to download it and use it that way.